# Creating debian package (.deb) for eclipse rcp product

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclipse-rcp, debian

Hello everyone on stackoverflow!

I have successfully developed and installed my Eclipse RCP product on Windows using `NSIS`.

#### Now I want to install on Ubuntu.

After searching the net, I figured out that using a debian package (.deb) for installing our software would be much easier for the end user.

I could execute my application after exporting it as product using `Export Wizard` but could not find any help on how to create `.deb` package from IDE.
So my question is:-

1. Do I need to add some plugin to my Eclipse IDE so that I can create a deb package?
2. If not then is there any way to create a `makefile` for my project in Eclipse so that I can create a .deb package as suggested [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html)

*(I am developing on `Ubuntu-12.04LTS` any help/suggestions/comments are highly appreciated as I am completely new to Ubuntu. thank you in advance)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some days ago I too had a same issue. That time I spend time on this, but then a simple shell script did the job. Please go through these links. They might help you -

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=838485

http://code.google.com/p/pkgcreator/

Another option is using STOW. You can find a tutorial on this over here -

http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/stow.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-stow/

Comment: creating the debian package worked for me. thanks a lot John. :-)